# Killing safely a delete large no. of records in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-delete, kill

I'm erasing 7M records on a db containing 22M records.
I started deleting using a classical `DELETE FROM db WHERE.`

I forgot to paginate :/

If I kill it, do I corrupt data? By saying corrupt I don't mean that I don't recover the deleted rows. I don't care about them. I just want the query to complete the deletion it is doing and stop there.

table Engine is **MyISAM**.

Comment: @diEcho I'm not sure you understand the problem at all. The OP isn't getting issues with a query being stopped due to max execution time being reached, they want to kill it manually.

Comment: @JamWaffles oh i really misread it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [KILL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/kill.html)

> During UPDATE or DELETE operations, the kill flag is checked after
>   each block read and after each updated or deleted row. If the kill
>   flag is set, the statement is aborted. Note that if you are not using
>   transactions, the changes are not rolled back.

It won't corrupt data. Your changes will be gone until kill(deletion stopped). And you are not bothering it at all. If you bother it then use transactions.

Comment: Perfect. Didn't thought to read the KILL chapter. Thank you very much.